# If $f(\sqrt{3-x})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is true for exhaustive domain of $f$, then domain of $f(x)$ is

Tags: functions

> If $f(\sqrt{3-x})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is true for exhaustive domain
> of $f$, then domain of $f(x)$ is ?

**My Approach:** I tried doing this by thinking what the function $f$ could be and this is what I came up with:

$f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3 - x^2}}$ since this satisfies the condition given in the question

Following this my domain came out be $x \in (-\sqrt{3} , \sqrt{3}]$. What did I do wrong ?

The answer given is:

> $x \in [0,\sqrt{3})$

Comment: $\sqrt 3$ is clearly not in the domain.

Answer (score 1):

We also need $x >0$ for all $x$ in the domain (so that $\frac 1  {\sqrt x}$ is defined). So the domain is $(0,\sqrt 3)$.